# How to send items list using ajax and jquery and how to extract the data from that in perl script so that it can add in Database

Tags: jquery, perl

I am trying to develop one shopping site. while users adds items in cart, i don't want to hit DB for each "ADD to cart" operation, instead every thing will be stored in j-query variables.
When user hit the button "Checkout", i want to add everything in DB.

The issue, i am facing is how to send all the item list to perl script, using ajax Jquery call? and how to extract information from that in perl script, and add rows in DB.

1 way i can think of create an array and send it to perl script.

```
var items = [
  { "itemname": "item1", "mrpprice": 22.00, "sellprice" : 21.50, "quantity": 2},
  { "itemname": "item2", "mrpprice": 24.00, "sellprice" : 22.50, "quantity": 1}
];


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/cgi-bin/submit_order.pl", // URL of the Perl script
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { itemsArray : items },
    success: function(data){
          alert ("success"); }
 });
```

in perl script

```
my @values = $cgi->param('itemsArray[]');
my $quan = $values[0]{'quantity'};
```

but the above in perl is not working.

The problem is i am not able to extract the information perl script. Can anyone suggest me any better way for the complete thing or guide me in extract the information in perl.

Your help will be appreciated.

Devesh

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know what kind of request the jQuery is sending , Data::Dumper the $cgi object, naturally, or $cgi->dump;
I get with `data: { 'toy_number': items },`

```
                  "toy_number[0][itemname]"  => ["item1"],
                  "toy_number[0][mrpprice]"  => [22],
                  "toy_number[0][quantity]"  => [2],
                  "toy_number[0][sellprice]" => [21.5],
                  "toy_number[1][itemname]"  => ["item2"],
                  "toy_number[1][mrpprice]"  => [24],
                  "toy_number[1][quantity]"  => [1],
                  "toy_number[1][sellprice]" => [22.5],
```

I expect you'd get similar